# Quil editor unable to read value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, text-editor

I am printing the html codes to the database with the quil editor, but when I want to display it, it cannot read the value, what could be the problem?

Here's how to make the code

```
  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div id="editor"><%=support.supportDetails%></div>
    
  </div>
```

It prints the data from the database directly to the editor with html codes without processing it, but I want to use it with functions, how do I do this?

Example image output

[image]